# synchronized a oracle package that invoked from jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

In my program data model, exist a table with two column as following:
`Id_1` and `Id_2` with `Number` data type. This table hasn't any primary key and unique key.

I have a package with a procedure as `persist`. This procedure using for adding a row to the table.
My procedure in package is as following:

```
procedure persist(id_1              out Number,
                  id_2              out Number)is
begin
    insert into middle_table values(id_1,id_2);
end;
```

Problem is: I have a scenario as following:
Thread one and thread 2 concurrent call above procedure with same parameter and result is : 2 equals row added to above table and this wrong in my application.

My question is: What I do for prevent this situation in procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always have a constraint, but still this requirement may be valid in some cases.

A Simple and elegant solution is to do a `MERGE` or do a `SELECT` and `INSERT`. So how many times, the proc is executed, you are safe.

You can have client side implementation by putting the procedure call in a `syncronized` method of your thread class. So, it cant be run parallely.

```
public void your_method() { 
     // Other statements

    synchronized( this ) { // blocks "this" from being executed by parallel threads
      // call your oracle stored proc here
    } 

}
```

But if there are multiple clients across different platforms, you may have to write something in Oracle itself!
A Simple and elegant solution is to do a `MERGE` or do a `SELECT` and `INSERT`

```
procedure persist(id_1              out Number,
                  id_2              out Number)
is
   retcode NUMBER := 0;
begin
    retcode := 100;
    /* Checking for semaphore, else wait ! */
    WHILE(retcode = 100)
    LOOP
         retcode = check_semphore(); /* Returns 100 if present else 0 */
         IF(retcode = 100) THEN
           /* Semaphore present */
           NULL;
         ELSE
           write_semaphore;
            /* probably a entry in a table with commit, 
            have to use savepoints, else every other transactions would be comitted! */

           MERGE INTO  middle_table m
           USING (SELECT id_1,id_2 FROM dual) new_Values
             ON ( new_Values.id_1 = m.id_1 
              AND new_Values.id_2 = m.id_2)
           WHEN NOT MATCHED
           THEN
               INSERT INTO middle_table VALUES(id_1,id_2);

          delete_semaphore; 
          /* delete tht entry */

          EXIT;

       END IF;
    END LOOP;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a unique constraint to the table in question?

or instead of having the threads writing directly to the db put the new objects in a hashtable, check for duplicate, join the threads and then use JPA to persit the objects found in the hashtable.